# Resetting Index in a Dataframe drops the Indexed column by 1 row

Tags: python, pandas

I am setting the index by removing the default dataframe index. Post setting a the new index. The column header with which i have set the index drops by 1 row. While the other columns are on 0 row. The indexed column name is on row 1.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

team_data=pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename()
                        ,header = 0)
empl_data=pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename()
                           , header = 0)
group_data_applied=pd.merge(left=team_data,right=empl_data,on = 'Empl ID')
group_data_applied.set_index('Empl ID',inplace=True)
```

Before Setting Index:

[image]

After Setting Index:
[image]

How do i see that all the columns are in the same axis.
Regards,
Ren.

Comment: If you want them to appear on the same row, you need to remove the name of your index: `df.index.name=None`, after setting the index. But regardless, this is just display formatting and really doesn't affect your data

Comment: @ALollz I agree it does not affect my data. However when i send the dataframe in an email it shows up the way after i have set the index. Does not look good. So i am trying to avoid same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a presentation issue, consider using [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) with `index=False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col2': [4, 5, 6]})

print(df.to_string(index=False))

col1  col2
   1     4
   2     5
   3     6
```

---

If you are set on removing your index name, you can set it to `None`:

```
df.index.name = None
```

Or, with operator chaining, use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col2': [4, 5, 6]})

df = df.set_index('col1').rename_axis(None)

print(df)

   col2
1     4
2     5
3     6
```

Comment: '=agency.set_index('Empl ID').rename_axis(None)  
    agency.rename_axis("Empl ID",inplace=True,axis=1)' Made this change and it comes in same axis. using string the entire dataframe does not look like a table.